# Borrowing changes type of Vector

Tags: vector, rust

Originally I wrote this:

```
fn split_line(line: &String) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut chars = line.chars();
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    let mut s = String::from("");
    while let Some(x) = chars.next() {
        match x {
            '<' => {},
            '/' => {
                        vec.push(s);
                        break;
                    }
            ' ' => {
                        vec.push(s);
                        s.clear();
                    }
            _ => s.push(x),
        }
    }
    vec
}
```

and received this error:
`use of moved value: 's'`
so I changed `vec.push(s)` to `vec.push(&s)`, which removed my original error, but changed vec from `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>` to `std::vec::Vec<&std::string::String>`.

Why? How can I borrow s without changing vec?

Comment: Dosen't this make a vector of empty strings?  Just varying the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `vec.push(s)`, `s` is moved into the vector, which means `s` no longer holds a meaningful value. All you need to do is reset `s` to a new `String`.

```
fn split_line(line: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut chars = line.chars();
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    let mut s = String::new();
    while let Some(x) = chars.next() {
        match x {
            '<' => {},
            '/' => {
                vec.push(s);
                break;
            }
            ' ' => {
                vec.push(s);
                s = String::new();
            }
            _ => s.push(x),
        }
    }
    vec
}
```

Comment: That or `vec.push(s.clone())`.

Comment: But `String::new()` doesn't allocate right away. :)

Comment: Okay, so vec becomes the owner of s. Thank you.